# BitmapFactory.decodeResource Bitmap not original size in pixels

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I have this code that crop a portion of a image sheet.

The problem is when I use `BitmapFactory.decodeResource` and when log the width and height, the size is not the same as the original.

```
Bitmap spriteSheet = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.imageSheet);

Log.i("Sprite Sheet Size",spriteSheet.getWidth()+"w "+spriteSheet.getHeight()+"h");
```

This is the log `1536w 330h` but the original size of the drawable(png) is `1024x220`

How do decode my resources to bitmap in their original sizes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The image is scaled according to the dpi of the device you are using, you can put the resources in `res/drawable-nodpi` or `res/drawable` folder to get the correct size

Comment: To me works using the res/drawable-nodpi folder. Using res/drawable does not work.